# How to use PHP to prepare serialized data string for database insert

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, serialization

I have a web form that serializes a list of radio inputs to the following string (where the number stands for the GameID and the school name indicates the Winner):

```
1=Boise+State&2=Michigan+State&4=Florida&3=Memphis
```

I pass this using an AJAX post to a .php script to be inserted into the database.
I am having trouble parsing the "GameID" and "Winner" data from the serialized string and into variables. I would like it to go into an INSERT statement as follows.

SCRIPT

```
$('#saveBtn').click(function(){
    confidence = $('#confidenceSort').sortable('serialize');
    winners = $('#winners').serialize();
    $.post("postpicks.php", confidence, 
        function(result){
            //do stuff
        })
    $.post("postpicks.php", winners, 
        function(result){
            //do stuff
        })
    });
```

PHP

```
$a1=array("=","&");
$a2=array("=>",",");
$dataArray = array(str_replace($a1,$a2,$_POST['winners']));
foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value){
    $query = "REPLACE INTO picks SET
            winner = '".$value."'
            WHERE gameid = ".$key.",
            AND userid='".$uid."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if (!$result) {errmsg('A database error occurred. Please contact Ryan.');}
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: `$gameid` is never set, and your wide open to sql injection

Comment: Thanks. How do I set $gameID to the number values from the string?

Comment: Please show the rest of your code.

Comment: Please show the whole HTTP request including all request headers and the request body.

Comment: I can validate that the variable gets set to the serialized string in my first code segment. Just need help parsing $gameId

Comment: I updated my code (see above) to show the changes I implemented. I think my problem is that the $.post isn't successfully passing the "winners" variable. Do you think it's a problem calling $.post twice on a single button click?

Comment: @RyanMiller What can I say.. Let me tell somethings .. 1) check to how to pass variables {} in one step not twice ..2) check your variables after passing it to php alert(data) in callback function in $.post .. 3) make your variables as an array after passing it to php and print_r it before you update your database .. Thats what I should say .. Good Luck and enjoy coding and testing :)